# Add custom field to group field ACF - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i am using wordpress 4.1 with ACF v4. I have a custom post type with custom fields added and need add a new custom field each time a new category is added. If i add the category "Sedan" automaticly i have to add the custom field "Sedan". Can I do this with the plugin functions? Or I have to do this with code, with inserts in database? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a dynamically built category selector within ACF, look into the [Taxonomy Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/).

This will generate a list based on specified taxonomy (categories is an option). The field will return either the Taxonomy Term object (if you use a single select option such as radio buttons), or an array of objects (if you use a multiselect option such as checkboxes). You could also set the field to return the Term ID instead.

Comment: No, i have a group fields with one custom field per each category, like this image [link]http://es.tinypic.com/r/119tsmb/8
If i add a new category i want a new field for this category. If add the category "Chairs" i want have a field "tab" and the field "product" related to this category "Chairs".
Thanks